# Resizing a Jpeg on server side with PHP

Tags: php, jpeg, image-resizing

I would like to resize images on server side to make thumbnail dynamicaly.
I'm using this code :

```
<?php
Header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
$img_src = $_GET['photo']; 

$size = getimagesize($img_src);

$src_w = $size[0];
$src_h = $size[1]; 

$dst_w = 80;
$dst_h = 80;

$test_h = round(($dst_w / $src_w) * $src_h); 
$test_w = round(($dst_h / $src_h) * $src_w); 


if($src_w > $src_h) {
    $x = $test_w;
    $y = $dst_h;
} elseif($src_h > $src_w) {
    $x = $dst_w;
    $y = $test_h;
}

$img_new = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_src); 
$img_mini = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y); 
imagecopyresampled($img_mini,$img_new,0,0,0,0,$x,$y,$src_w,$src_h); 
imagejpeg($img_mini); 
?>
```

But it didn't work, and I can't find why. There is no error, juste nothing appeared.
Can anybody help me ?

Thanks;

Comment: What is $_GET['photo'] ... is it a URL?

Comment: Have you tried `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: $_GET['photo'] is the passed URL to the picture : "?photo=Galery/Paysages/050520111625.jpg" for exemple.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) didn't return anything.

Comment: please try to dump all the variables along the way like `$size`. I'm pretty sure you can't read the file

Comment: @Bahaïka i personally use this api for resizing images http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/ its very easy to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a blank page, then either your script timed out or php memory limit was exceeded. Use `ini_set` function to set `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` before starting any gd function.

Image manipulations take time as well as memory. So these configurations are important.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line:

```
$size = getimagesize($img_src);
```

Where have you defined `$img_src`? I can't see it!

**EDIT**
Use this code to write the file to disk and then redirect to the written file:

```
<?php

$chemin = $_GET['photo']; 

$size = getimagesize($chemin);


$src_w = $size[0];
$src_h = $size[1]; 

$dst_w = 80;
$dst_h = 80;

$test_h = round(($dst_w / $src_w) * $src_h); 
$test_w = round(($dst_h / $src_h) * $src_w); 


if($src_w > $src_h) {
    $x = $test_w;
    $y = $dst_h;
} elseif($src_h > $src_w) {
    $x = $dst_w;
    $y = $test_h;
}

$img_new = imagecreatefromjpeg($chemin); 
$img_mini = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y); 

imagecopyresampled($img_mini, $img_new, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x ,$y, $src_w, $src_h); 

$name=rand() * rand() . '.jpg';

imagejpeg($img_mini, $name); 
header("Location: $name");

?>
```

Comment: It was a copy/paste error, i've edtied my first post to correct it. Sorry.

Comment: Now there's no `$chemin` man...
Anyway, it's a properly working script, if you output to a file instead of to the browser

Comment: Seems to be some garbling of the bytes when they pass over http, because it works PERFECTLY when you output to the filesystem. I've edited the answer, check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting an error, I would work with a test image that you know, and work through this line by line, confirming that you are getitng the results you are expecting, untily you find the line(s) that are causing issues. Check the expected return results for those functions and make conditionals that output where this code is getting stuck or where you are not getting the result you want.

Example:

```
if (isset($img_src)) {
    echo "No image parameter set in the URL";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to translate the url you are getting into an actual file path so that you can open the file.  I expect that the functions you are using expect a file path, not a url.  If not, they should otherwise you're doing 2 extra requests just to avoid downloading one image and resizing via CSS on the client.

In any event, if you're going to resize to a thumbnail you really should be caching the thumbnail in a `thumbs` (or other) subdirectory.  Then on each request, check if the thumbnail is exists, serving it up directly if so, before creating the thumbnail.  Or, if the files aren't dynamically uploaded, pre-create the thumbnails and just reference them from the `thumbs`  directory directly.